# Differential Equation For Constant Survival

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need to solve the equation

$$\frac{df}{dt} - f\frac{df}{dt} = k$$
(k constant).

I've got as far as

$$\frac{d}{dt}(2f - f^2) = 2k$$

and therefore

$$f^2 - 2f = c - 2kt$$
($c$ is integration constant)

but am not sure how to progress.

Comment: you have an equation of 2 order in $f$...

Comment: That's right. I tried a couple of subtitutions for f with exponential functions, and polynomial * exponential but nothing fits

Answer (score 1):

The equation $f^2-2f=c-2kt$ is quadratic equation in $f$ from algebra 2, not a differential equation. So there is no need to do any substitutions. $f^2-2f=c-2kt$ implies $f^2-2f+1=1+c-2kt=(f-1)^2$, so $f-1=\pm\sqrt{C-2kt}$, implying $f=1\pm\sqrt{C-2kt}$. To verify this is accurate, $f'=\pm\frac{-k}{\sqrt{C-2kt}}$, hence $ff'=\pm\frac{-k}{\sqrt{C-2kt}}-k=\mp\frac{2k}{\sqrt{C-2kt}}-k$, so $f'-ff'=\pm\frac{-k}{\sqrt{C-2kt}}-\left(\mp\frac{k}{\sqrt{C-2kt}}-k\right)=k$.